# onClick={handleClick} inside a div doesn't work when it's outputted from a .map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

I have a rendered output that maps each item I have from an array into a div like this

```
    var renderedOutput = arr.map(item => <div key={item.portfolioName} style={portfolioStyle} onClick={handleClick}> {item.portfolioName} </div>)
```

Although the key={...} and style={...} inside the div work completely fine,
Using onClick={handleClick} does not? How can I fix this?

**Here is the rest of my code:**

```
export default function Sidebar(props){
    var user = props.user    
    var arr = user.user.portfolios
    
    const portfolioStyle = {
        textAlign: "left",
        border: "1px",
    }

    var renderedOutput = arr.map(item => <div key={item.portfolioName} style={portfolioStyle} onClick={handleClick}> {item.portfolioName} </div>)

    const handleClick = e => {
        alert('works')
    }

    return (
       <>
         <div>
             {renderedOutput}
         </div>
       </>
    )
}
```

**The functionality I wish to create:**
For each item in the array, a row is created with

1. The name of the portfolio, which directs you to its respective page when clicked
2. An edit button and delete button

For now I just have an alert in place in the handleClick of the divs to test if it even works. But nothing happens, the handleClick never runs

Comment: How is `handleClick` not working? Can you post some more code?

Comment: it is a class Component or a Function component? and needs some more code like `handleClick` method

Comment: I moved `handleClick` above `renderedOutput` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because it isn't finding the the ***`handleClick`*** function. You need to call the function before the initialization of ***`renderedOutput`***. So, update your code like this:

```js
export default function Sidebar(props){
    var user = props.user    
    var arr = user.user.portfolios
    
    const portfolioStyle = {
        textAlign: "left",
        border: "1px",
    }

    const handleClick = e => {
        alert('works')
    }

    var renderedOutput = arr.map(item => <div key={item.portfolioName} style={portfolioStyle} onClick={handleClick}> {item.portfolioName} </div>)

    return (
       <>
         <div>
             {renderedOutput}
         </div>
       </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is working correctly :

```
const object={
    user:
    {
      portfolios:
      [
        {portfolioName:'a'},
      {portfolioName:'b'}
    ]
    }
  };
export function Sidebar(props){
  var user = props.props.user;    
  var arr = user.portfolios;
  
  const portfolioStyle = {
      textAlign: "left",
      border: "1px",
  }
  const handleClick = e => {
    alert('works')
  }
  var renderedOutput = arr.map(item => <div key={item.portfolioName} style={portfolioStyle} onClick={handleClick}> {item.portfolioName} </div>)

  return (
     <>
       <div>
           {renderedOutput}
       </div>
     </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because **renderedOutput** initialized first, do change in your code. Move **handleClick** before renderedOutput.

```
export default function Sidebar(props){
            var user = props.user    
            var arr = user.user.portfolios
            
            const portfolioStyle = {
                textAlign: "left",
                border: "1px",
            }
        
            const handleClick = e => {
                alert('works')
            }
        
            var renderedOutput = arr.map(item => <div key={item.portfolioName} style={portfolioStyle} onClick={handleClick}> {item.portfolioName} </div>)
        
            return (
               <>
                 <div>
                     {renderedOutput}
                 </div>
               </>
            )
        }
```